# Class inheritance: Function is inaccessible

Tags: c++, inheritance, access-specifier

I'm getting this error, but I thought I would only get it if the member's protection level was too high and made it inaccessible, but I'm getting it anyway.

Shopable.h:

```
#ifndef _SHOPABLE_H_
#define _SHOPABLE_H_

#include "Library.h"

class Shopable{
private:
    std::string Name;
    int Cost;
    std::string Description;
public:
    std::string getName() const{return Name;}
    int getCost() const {return Cost;}
    virtual std::string getDesc() const = 0;
};

#endif
```

Weapon.h:

```
#ifndef _WEAPON_H_
#define _WEAPON_H_

#include "Globals.h"
#include "Shopable.h"

class Weapon : Shopable{
private:
    int Damage;
public:
    Weapon(int Cost,int Damage,std::string Name) : Cost(Cost), Damage(Damage), Name(Name){}
    std::string getDesc() const{
        return getName()+"\t"+tostring(Damage)+"\t"+tostring(Cost);
    }
    int Damage(Entity *target){
        int DamageDealt = 0;
        //do damage algorithm things here
        Special();
        return DamageDealt;
    }
};

#endif
```

Some line in a random function with the correct includes:

```
std::map< std::string, Weapon* > weapons;
Weapon* none = new Weapon(0,0,"None");
weapons[none->getName()] = none;
```

The error is with getName() - "Error: function 'Shopable::getName' is inaccessible"

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You want public inheritance:

```
 class Weapon : Shopable
```

should be:

```
 class Weapon : public Shopable
```

Also, names like `_SHOPABLE_H_` are illegal in user written C++ code, as they are reserved for the C++ implementation. Forget the leading underscores and use `SHOPABLE_H`.

And:

```
 Weapon(int Cost,int Damage,std::string Name)
```

should be:

```
 Weapon(int Cost,int Damage, const std::string & Name )
```

to avoid the unnecessary overhead of copying the string.

You might want to rethink your naming convention - typically, function parameter names in C++ begin with a lower case latter. Names beginning with uppercase letters are typically reserved for user-defined types (i.e. classes, struct, enums etc.)

As a matter of interest, which C++ textbook are you learning from?

Comment: I wasn't using a textbook, just picking up bits and pieces from places on the internet.

Answer (score 13):

The inheritance must be public:

```
class Weapon : public Shopable
```

Answer (score 13):

You're using private inheritance:

```
class Weapon : Shopable
```

So the fact that a Weapon is a Shopable is not visible to other classes. Change it to public inheritance:

```
class Weapon : public Shopable
```

Comment: Isn't implicit inheritance `protected`?

Comment: @Gustav: no, it's public for `struct`, and private for `class`.

Comment: @Mike I had to check because I got curious, and you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 7):

`class`es default to private inheritance, `struct`s to public. You're using `class`, so you need to use `: public Base` if you want to model "is-a":

```
class Weapon : public Shopable{ // added "public"
```

Answer (score 5):

You get private inheritance by not specifying anything else. Try this instead

```
class Weapon : public Shopable{
```